# Delay between each recursive call to function

Tags: javascript, recursion, promise, settimeout, delay

I am trying to build a maze generator for a personal project. I have a recursive depth-first search function that recursively goes through each cell in the grid, checks if it has unvisited neighbors, then calls the recursive function again with the next neighbor. It is able to generate the maze just fine but I want to add a delay between each call to the recursive function so I can animate the creation of the maze as it visits each cell. Using the chrome debugger, it seems to do the 1s delay for the first iteration and then it stops waiting and jumps from the await delay back to the beginning of the function over and over without ever moving on. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the recursive function and delay function:

```
async function recursiveDFS(currentCell) {
    await delay(1000);
    highlightCell(currentCell);
    currentCell.visited = true;
    var [next, direction] = getNextNeighbor(currentCell);

    while(typeof(next) != 'undefined') {
        removeWall(currentCell, next, direction);
        highlightCell(next);
        recursiveDFS(next);
        [next, direction] = getNextNeighbor(currentCell);
    }
}

function delay(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, ms)
    });
}
```

and here is the full javascript code:

```
"use strict"

// declare globals
const numCols = 10;
const numRows = 10;
const cellSize = 50;
var grid = [];

// create canvas
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.id = 'canvas';
canvas.width = numCols * cellSize;
canvas.height = numRows * cellSize;
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
body.appendChild(canvas);
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

function setup() {
    createGrid();
    const start = grid[0][0]; // start at top left cell
    const end = grid[1][1];
    recursiveDFS(start);
}

class Cell {
    constructor(col, row) {
        this.col = col;
        this.row = row;
        this.neighbors = {};
        this.walls = {
            top: true,
            right: true,
            bottom: true,
            left: true
        };
        this.visited = false;
    }

    setNeighbors() {
        //top
        if(this.row - 1 >= 0) {
            this.neighbors.top = grid[this.col][this.row - 1]; 
        }
        //right     
        if (this.col + 1 < numCols) {
            this.neighbors.right = grid[this.col + 1][this.row];
        }
        //bottom
        if (this.row + 1 < numRows) {
            this.neighbors.bottom = grid[this.col][this.row + 1];
        }
        //left
        if (this.col - 1 >= 0) {
            this.neighbors.left = grid[this.col - 1][this.row];
        }
    }
}

// create 2d array of Cell objects
        // indexing as grid[col][row]
        // grid = [[(0,0), (1,0)], 
        //         [(0,1), (1,1)]]
function createGrid() {
    for (var col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
        var colArr = []
        for (var row = 0;  row < numRows; row++) {
            var cell = new Cell(col, row);
            colArr.push(cell);
            drawGridLines(cell);
        }
        grid.push(colArr);
    }

    for (var row = 0;  row < numRows; row++) {
        for (var col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
            grid[col][row].setNeighbors();
        }
    }
}

// return single neighbor randomized from all possible neighbors
function getNextNeighbor(cell) {
    if (cell.neighbors) {
        var neighbors = [];
        for (var neighbor in cell.neighbors) {
            if (cell.neighbors[neighbor].visited === false){
                neighbors.push([cell.neighbors[neighbor], neighbor]);
            }
        }  
    } 
    if(neighbors.length > 0) {
        return neighbors[Math.floor(Math.random() * neighbors.length)]; 
    } else {
        return [undefined, undefined];
    }
}

function delay(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        console.log("waiting...");
        setTimeout(resolve, ms)
    });
} 

async function recursiveDFS(currentCell) {
    await delay(1000);
    highlightCell(currentCell);
    currentCell.visited = true;
    var [next, direction] = getNextNeighbor(currentCell);

    while(typeof(next) != 'undefined') {
        removeWall(currentCell, next, direction);
        highlightCell(next);
        recursiveDFS(next);
        [next, direction] = getNextNeighbor(currentCell);
    }
}

function highlightCell(cell) {
    context.globalCompositeOperation='destination-over'; // fill rect under existing grid
    const topLeft = [(cell.col) * cellSize, (cell.row) * cellSize];
    context.fillStyle = '#FF0000';
    context.fillRect(topLeft[0], topLeft[1], cellSize, cellSize);
}

function removeWall(cell1, cell2, direction) {
    switch (direction) {
        case 'top':
            cell1.walls.top = false;
            cell2.walls.bottom = false;
            break;
        case 'right':
            cell1.walls.right = false;
            cell2.walls.left = false;
            break;
        case 'bottom':
            cell1.walls.bottom = false;
            cell2.walls.top = false;
            break;
        case 'left':
            cell1.walls.left = false;
            cell2.walls.right = false;
            break;
    }
    redrawGrid();
}

function redrawGrid() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, numCols * cellSize, numRows * cellSize); // clear canvas
    for (var col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
        for (var row = 0;  row < numRows; row++) {
            drawGridLines(grid[col][row]);
        }
    }
}

function drawGridLines(cell) {
    const topLeft =     [ cell.col         * cellSize,  cell.row          * cellSize];
    const topRight =    [(cell.col + 1)    * cellSize,  cell.row          * cellSize];
    const bottomLeft =  [ cell.col         * cellSize, (cell.row + 1)     * cellSize];
    const bottomRight = [(cell.col + 1)    * cellSize, (cell.row + 1)     * cellSize];

    context.lineWidth = 2;

    //draw top line
    if(cell.walls.top){
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(topLeft[0], topLeft[1]);
        context.lineTo(topRight[0], topRight[1]);
        context.stroke();
    }

    //draw right line
    if(cell.walls.right) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(topRight[0], topRight[1]);
        context.lineTo(bottomRight[0], bottomRight[1]);
        context.stroke();
    }

    //draw bottom line
    if(cell.walls.bottom) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(bottomRight[0], bottomRight[1]);
        context.lineTo(bottomLeft[0], bottomLeft[1]);
        context.stroke();
    }

    //draw left line
    if(cell.walls.left) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(bottomLeft[0], bottomLeft[1]);
        context.lineTo(topLeft[0], topLeft[1]);
        context.stroke();
    }
}


setup();
```

Comment: Move the delay into the loop. Or `await recuroveDFS(next)`

Comment: yep, `await recursiveDFS(next);` if you want to wait

Comment: Thank you that worked! Wow I wish I would have posted this question a long time ago I've been struggling with that for a while. Would you be able to explain why that is? Why is awaiting the delay not enough? It's my understanding that when the function reaches an await it stops everything in the function and jumps to other processes in the call stack or the queues to execute.

Comment: @Britt It only stops the current function call. Not everything on the call stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
async function recursiveDFS(currentCell) {
        await delay(1000);
        highlightCell(currentCell);
        currentCell.visited = true;
        var [next, direction] = getNextNeighbor(currentCell);
    
        while(typeof(next) != 'undefined') {
            removeWall(currentCell, next, direction);
            highlightCell(next);
            await recursiveDFS(next);
            [next, direction] = getNextNeighbor(currentCell);
        }
    }
```

Add await when u call recursiveDFS(next); so that it will wait for the function to be done before going to the next step as you have set the function as async.